# move a robot to a point goal

Tags: ros, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to order a robot to moves towards a goal Point and simulation in stageros.
For this I created a node to publish Vitess lineare and angular about cmd_vel, then what I want to know is how to adjust the angular.z Vitess to rotate the robot at an angle of 45 ° for exmple

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227244/move-a-robot-to-a-point-goal/) by [ragnard](https://answers.ros.org/users/26010/ragnard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

to rotate the robot by a certain angle, you have to choose a rotational velocity and compute for how long you should send it. for example, to rotate 45 degrees you can publish an angular velocity of 4.5 degrees/s during 10 seconds.

bear in mind that in this way, you are commanding the robot in an open loop, so due to accelerations and other errors you will not get exactly the orientation or the position that you expected.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ragnard](https://answers.ros.org/users/26010/ragnard/) on 2016-02-25**:
thank you, it looks interesting idea, but I managed to make the angle of the shot I want, is recovering the rotation of the robot odometry and put a condition when the rotation equal to the angle I want, I'm doing the robot stoper

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-02-25**:
yes, that is the way to go. by doing that, you are effectively commanding the robot in a closed loop.